# Same Model for different relation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to use my File Model with two other models.

```
App.File = DS.Model.extend({
   filename: DS.attr('string'),
   //related:DS.belongsTo('App.Task' and 'App.Comment'),
});

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    files:DS.hasMany('App.Files'),
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    comment:DS.attr('string'),
    files:DS.hasMany('App.Files'),
});
```

The database structure has a related_id and related_type column. How can I set this up to work with ember?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you'd have to add `tasks` and `comments` properties as `belongsTo` in your `File` model.